# How to open the .dSYM package to view the symbols list?

Tags: dsym

I read that the symbols list of an IOS app are in the .dSYM. I would like to view the entire list of symbols, do you guys know what tool do I need to use to extract this information from this package?

thanks

-Malena

Answer (score 16):

You can use **dwarfdump**.

For example to see all **public** types in a dSYM-file for ARM64 architecture run:

```
dwarfdump --arch arm64 --debug-pubtypes YourFramework.framework.dSYM/
```

<sub>`pub` is just short for `public`.</sub>

For more information check the man-page of dwarfdump. Using this command you can also extract strings, filter by name and address and more.